# Как сделать глобальную переменную в WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Можно ли сделать, чтобы я мог использовать массив ***arr*** по всему проекту. Массив ***arr*** я не могу использовать в *private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)*.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double[] arr = new double[(int)numericUpDown1.Value];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            dataGridView1.RowCount = 1;
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = rnd.NextDouble() * 78.4 - 27.8;
                arr[i] = Math.Round(arr[i], 1);
                dataGridView1[i, 0].Value = arr[i];
                dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText = i.ToString();
            }
            var MaxValue = arr.Max();
            var MinValue = arr.Min();
            var IndexMin = Array.IndexOf(arr, MinValue);
            var IndexMax = Array.IndexOf(arr, MaxValue);
            var min = Math.Min(IndexMin, IndexMax);
            var max = Math.Max(IndexMin, IndexMax);
            Int64 IndexProduct = 1;
            for (var i = min + 1; i < max; i++)
            {
                IndexProduct *= i;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                double sum = 0;
                Array.Sort(arr);
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                    dataGridViewArray[i, 0].Value = arr[i];
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                    if (arr[i] > 0)
                        sum += arr[i];
                textBoxSumma.Text = sum.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double[] arr;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  arr = new double[(int)numericUpDown1.Value];
  ...

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (arr == null)
    return;
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class Globals
{
   public static double[] arr;
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   //...
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Globals.arr = new double[(int)numericUpDown1.Value];
      //...
   }
}
```

Comment: Глобальные переменные - зло. Не нужно начинающим давать способ использовать их. Тем более, автору достаточно поля класса (формы).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а смысл? Глобальных переменных в C# нет, только статические классы, которые подходят для данной цели. А если ему надо будет передавать данные между формами? До освоения наследования классов делегаты/события учить? Action<>'ами и Func<>"ами пугать? Мне в своём время про статические классы никто не сказал, такой говнокод шляпал... что в итоге родительская и дочерняя формы знали друг о друге всё, и спокойно манипулировали полями друг-друга.